# How can I retrieve a name from the Id

Tags: c#

How do I grab something like Name using the ID?

Code:

```
//PROPRIEDADES
    public int Id
    {
        get { return id; }
        set
        {
            if (value < 0)
                throw new Exception("ID inválido");
            id = value;
        }
    }
    public string Username { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
    public string Nome_Completo { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
```

...

CollectionBase:

```
    public string idToName(int id)
    {
       foreach (Pessoa p in this.List)
       {
           if (p.Id == id)
           {
            return p.Nome_Completo;
           }
       }
      return null;
    }
```

Final result:
TABLE A: https://i.stack.imgur.com/deaCe.jpg NEED TO GET THE NOME_COMPLETO
TABLE B: https://i.stack.imgur.com/2gXi5.jpg

Me trying to get the NAME FROM ID:

```
private void LoadListView()
{
  lstvEncomendas.Items.Clear();
  foreach (Encomenda en in brain.encomendas)
  {
        string[] subitems = new string[] { en.Id.ToString(), brain.pessoas.idToName(en.PessoaID)/*en.PessoaID.ToString()*/, en.Morada, en.Telefone, en.Descricao, en.Attachfile.ToString(), en.VoluntarioID.ToString(), en.Estado};

        ListViewItem lviItem = new ListViewItem(subitems);

        lstvEncomendas.Items.Add(lviItem);
  }
```

}

Comment: Guessing that you want to find `Name` by `id`. Linq may help `string name = myList.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == id)?.Name` where `id` is local variable containing id. If returned `null`, means that id was not found.

Comment: Do I place that on my collection base instead of this:

public string idToName(int id)
    {
       foreach (Pessoa p in this.List)
       {
           if (p.Id == id)
           {
            return p.Nome_Completo;
           }
       }
      return null;
    }